# getting "android.content.res.resources$notfoundexception"

Tags: android, android-listview, contextmenu

I have 3 tabs and each tab has got a listview. I have registered these listviews for contextual menu. I have three different arraylists in which i store the items for respective listviews.

now i want the position of the item of listview which was clicked.

my code is :

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

      switch(item.getItemId()){

   case R.id.mycards_contextmenu_1:

       if(mCurrentTab.equals("Tab 1")){
           try{
           int pos= info.position;
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }catch(Exception e){
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           }
    break;

  }
```

i am getting

```
   android.content.res.resources$notfoundexception
```

where have I gone wrong?

EDIT:

```
Stack Trace :


 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:265)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at neeraj.cardXchange.myCardsPackage.myCardsActivity.onContextItemSelected(myCardsActivity.java:211)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2552)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3601)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:924)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 03-14 22:06:12.488: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What line is the error on? If you don't know, please post full stacktrace

Comment: int pos= info.position;

Comment: please paste full stack trace

Comment: stack trace added, 
i think i am getting the error wherever i use the pos value

Comment: You are getting error in toast statement as you look clouser to yout stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

should be

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`Toast` also has a [`makeText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) method that accepts in a String resource id (which is an `int`), and by pasing `pos`, you call that method, which can't find a String resource with that id, hence the

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
```

Comment: but how can i use the integer value of pos ??? 
i want the integer value of pos.....

Comment: further i want to use its value to write the delete function, where the "pos: will give the position of the item clicked ?

Comment: @user2056245 Toasts display something to the user and the method can either accept in a String or a String resource id. I converted `pos` to a String *just for* the Toast so it won't crash. You can continue to use `pos` as an `int` in your code because it is still an `int`.

Comment: i will try, but i got some error earlier, thats why i used toast to verify, and still i got the same error

Comment: @user2056245 if you implemented my solution and it is still not working, you should update the stack trace and code. `String.valueOf(pos)` should get rid of the `Resources$NotFoundException`